# I ran `mkfs.btrfs -f` on a disk containing an existing btrfs file system (HDD), can btrfs tools help me recover? If not, what else might I consider?

Tags: partition, data-recovery, btrfs

I did something very stupid yesterday.

I have two physical drives (both HDD), call them `X` and `Y`. Both contained (separate) `btrfs` file systems that extended over their whole size.

Let `@x` be a subvolume of `X` that I want(ed) to preserve.

I needed to relabel `X` and restructure its subvolume hierarchy. So I came up with the following plan:

1. create a snapshot of `@x` and store it on `Y` (through `send`/`receive`)
2. run `mkfs.btrfs​ -f` on `X` and create a new subvolume structure for it
3. `send`​ the snapshot `@x` from `Y` to `X`.
4. done; do other things.

My error was that I forgot to perform step 3, and then a script I wrote executed `mkfs.btrfs​` on `Y` (in error, I did not want to or need to reformat it; cause of the error: I did not realize that the labels `sda`/`sdb`/`sdc` are not "constant" between boots).

Luckily, `Y` had no data I cared apart from `@x`.

So now I have two disks `X` *and* `Y` which did hold `@x` in the past. Neither of them hold `@x` today, and both have had `mkfs.btrfs -f` executed on them. **Is it possible to recover `@x` at all?**

Some things I tried (but clearly, did not succeed):

1. trying to locate the older partition on `X` and `Y` using `testdisk` (it could detect them, I think, but considered them unrecoverable).
2. `btrfs restore` to try and find previous trees (both manually, and a little more "intelligently" using the [`undelete_btrfs`](https://github.com/danthem/undelete-btrfs)). No luck.

I can run `photorec` on the disks, and that does recover various data, but a lot of it might be junk data I no longer care for (there were a lot of older partitions, detected by `testdisk` including from when `X` and `Y` were supporting Windows machines). This is not really an issue, except for the fact that I don't have anywhere to store this recovered data *except for* `X` and `Y`.